# Pound sign in escaped powershell uri string

Tags: powershell

I'm using powershell to transfer data to my server.

I had an original question here: [Powershell downloadFile with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42010969/powershell-downloadfile-with-special-characters?noredirect=1#comment71200880_42010969) about trying to escape a string inside of batch, which I had no luck with. So I created the short powershell script here:

```
$model = $args[0]
$os = $args[1]
$gpu = $args[2]
$hdd = $args[3]
$ram = $args[4]
$processor = $args[5]
$realmodel = $args[6]
$realupc = $args[7]
$productnumber = $args[8]

$url = [uri]::EscapeUriString("http://example.com/otherdb/modelfinder/form.php?model=$model&os=$os&graphics=$gpu&hdd=$hdd&ram=$ram&processor=$processor&actualmodel=$realmodel&Implement=0&UPC=$realupc&otherIdentifier=$productnumber")

(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, 'save.txt')
```

Which successfully escapes the string and sends it to my server to be processed.

The problem is, near the end of my url, there is sometimes a pound sign `#` - which I believe powershell may be counting as a comment, or simply isn't being encoded. When checking my database after the url is sent, the `#` and everything after it is removed from the cell.

How can I encode the string to be sent exactly the way it is to be saved in my database?

Comment: works fine for me, PS5

Comment: @4c74356b41 Are you passing variables the same way? Could that be why? The actual `$productnumber` is `E0X70UA#ABA` - but the only thing saved in that cell is `E0X70UA`. Could it be my PHP script destroying that part of the string?

Comment: My bet is `EscapeUriString` does not do what you think it does. BTW `#` start [`Fragment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.uri.fragment.aspx) part of URI.

Comment: @PetSerAl Is there any way in PHP to process the `#` as plaintext from a variable?

Comment: Check the character encoding on the web server/db...

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Use `%23` instead of `#`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I don't type in the string. It is generated automatically.

Comment: [What's the difference between EscapeUriString and EscapeDataString?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4396598)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape your arguments separately as data strings. When you use `[uri]::EscapeUriString("#")` you will see that `#` will not be escaped.

```
PS > [uri]::EscapeUriString("#");
#
PS > [uri]::EscapeDataString("#")
%23
```

So as an abbreviated example, you could construct your string like this:

```
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new();
$model = "# model with hash sign"
$os = "some operating system with exclamation mark!!";
$sb.Append("http://example.com/otherdb/modelfinder/form.php?model=");
$sb.Append([uri]::EscapeDataString($model).ToString());
$sb.Append("&os=");
$sb.Append([uri]::EscapeDataString($os).ToString());
$sb.ToString();

http://example.com/otherdb/modelfinder/form.php?model=%23%20model%20with%20hash%20sign&os=some%20operating%20system%20with%20exclamation%20mark!!
```